# How to import a library not published on npm in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, import

I need to import a library "toystars/react-native-dynamic-forms".

I did `npm install git+https://github.com/toystars/react-native-dynamic-form.git`.

and in my app.js

`import DynamicForm from "react-native-dynamic-form"`

but I am getting an error

> "Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports."

I am using it like this:

```
import DynamicForm from "react-native-dynamic-form" ;     
<DynamicForm
    ref={ref => this.formRef = ref}
    form={formeg}
    style={styles.formContainer}/>
```

Comment: package.json as the following entry                                                                    "react-native-dynamic-form": "git+https://github.com/toystars/react-native-dynamic-form.git",

Comment: Try running `npm install react-native-dynamic-form --save`

Comment: @Firu tried the above and it says npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: react-native-dynamic-form@latest

Comment: you need to configure `react-native-vector-icons` to use this component. please check if you have integrated vector icons in your project. In the docs, they have clearly mentioned to add react-native vector icons.

Comment: yes its there... "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0", and linked

Comment: it also gives me this error"Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-dynamic-form'. '/node_modules/react-native-dynamic-form/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/react-native-dynamic-form` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-native-dynamic-form';`ts(7016)"